# How can I prevent posts with no title showing up in my query?

Tags: theme-development, wp-query, loop, post-formats

How do I prevent posts with no title showing up in my query / loop ? ( I am doing aside, quote etc post-formats and I want to exclude title less posts from one particular loop)

I have nothing on this. I searched through [`WP_Query`](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGkQFjAB&url=http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query&ei=4XUtUO-JNYuDhQevu4HQCw&usg=AFQjCNFjSQ_s-LVXT7_Syz2PSYsZbpeVgg&sig2=sU6Cq9oDMuM-N-_i6twVQg) on this but I can't find anything, and when I try google everything is muddied with 'not display title stuff' etc. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles , maybe you can do a query

Comment: How complex is your query? Can you post a sample here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below a quick solution to your problem

1. first query for all empty titles
2. place the result in an array
3. query again for post__not_in
   see below sample code

   ```
   $query = new WP_Query('post_title=\'\'');
   $a_empty_titles = array();
    while($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        array_push( $a_empty_titles ,$query->post->ID);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
    echo count($a_empty_titles);
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => $a_empty_titles ) );
    //your loop code here
    //reset query
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
   ```

Comment: actually i cant get it to work - `$query = new WP_Query('post_title=\'\'');` seems to not be exactly right, it picks up on more than just posts with no title for some reason. I cant figure out what causes it to pick certain posts that do have titles. Any ideas. I will work on it again later.

Comment: try this code: global $wpdb;
 $not_empty_titles = $wpdb->get_results( 
 "
 SELECT ID
 FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_title != ''
 ",ARRAY_N  );
 print_r($not_empty_titles);

Comment: [Class Reference WPDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for reference

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure that would work, though I was trying to avoid querying directly ... based on your original idea I was able to get it working something like this ... thanks ....  `$a_empty_titles = array();
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish' );
$fp_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $fp_posts as $post ) 
if ( ! $post->post_title )
array_push($a_empty_titles,$post->ID);   
$args = array( 'post__not_in' => $a_empty_titles );`