# How to exclude post body from WP search

Tags: search

My WooCommerce site uses the default WP search.  The one thing that I need to change is to exclude the post body from the search (in my case, the product description).

Right now, the search searches title, body, taxonomy terms.  I want it to search only title and taxonomy terms.

To clarify, I don't want to simply exclude the product description from displaying on the search resultspage.  I want to stop the search engine from looking in the product description.  ie:  Search engine should only look for matches in the product name and taxonomy terms.

I searched high and low and can't find info how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your search template

Comment: How would that help??  The search template page simply displays the search results.  I want different search results.  For example, I may have only 3 products with "American" in the product name, but 15 with "American" in the product description.  When someone searches for "American", I only want the 3 products to come up.  Seems to me that I need to hook into the search function, not customize the search template.

Comment: Thats not what you said in your question. "The one thing that I need to change is to exclude the post body". The Search template determines what is displayed. So you can hide or show any parts of a post by editing the template. If that is not what you want to do please update your question to be more accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to limit search to post titles?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles)

Answer (score 1):

To remove elements from being searched, use the post_search filter to amend the SQL query for the search e.g. only pull in the title.

```
function ni_search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ){
 global $wpdb;
 if ( empty( $search ) )
  return $search;
 $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
 $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
 $search =
 $searchand = '';
 foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
  $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
  $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
  $searchand = ' AND ';
 }
 if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
  $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
   $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
 }
 return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'ni_search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

Taken from https://nathaningram.com/restricting-wordpress-search-to-titles-only/

Personally I prefer a plugin for this as it gives me full control over every field I want in my search, the one I use is [relevanssi](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/). It should do what you want really easily.