# Ignore posts content in the posts queries for internal linking

Tags: posts, query, admin, linking

I am looking for a filter to ignore searching in posts **content** from the posts editor which is natively using the link function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_editors/wp_link_query/

Use case: with 300,000 articles, the query is too slow, searching in titles and excerpt is good enough.

Internal linking happens in the Classic Editor; example below:

[image: Capture of the WordPress Internal Linking autocomplete]

Action:

- /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Form Data:

- action: wp-link-ajax
- page: 1
- search: Hello world

Thank you,

**UPDATE**:

I changed in class-wp-query.php the line:

`$search   .= $wpdb->prepare( "{$searchand}(({$wpdb->posts}.post_title $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_excerpt $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content $like_op %s))", $like, $like, $like );`

To:

`$search   .= $wpdb->prepare( "{$searchand}(({$wpdb->posts}.post_title $like_op %s) $andor_op ({$wpdb->posts}.post_excerpt $like_op %s))", $like, $like, $like );`

I wish there could be a more simple way to do so!

Comment: That query is actually quite fast, it only fetches 20 posts, it doesn't update any caches, and it uses the default search functionality. Searching only in titles or excerpts will have negligible savings as those are all in the main posts table and have various indexes for performances. Unless you've put plugins in that hook into the filters, this kind of query should be quite fast even at 300k articles. As for too slow, can you be specific? half a second? 5 seconds? 100 seconds? In the block editor? In the classic editor? In WPBakery? In Elementor? etc

Comment: I agree with @Laurent. But if you even want to try something, take a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles).

Comment: @TomJNowell 
From the classic editor.
It fetches 20 posts but needs to go through the whole DB when nothing matches. We also use a multilanguage plugin, which forces every search to search in the related active language (which joins on the taxonomies table).
How slow? I am talking about the request taking 1.5 seconds without searching in content vs 4 to 10 seconds when searching in content (up to 30~45 seconds sometimes, eg, when having multiple keywords).

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves, the "posts_search" filter does not apply to the internal linking request. I want to find a similar way for these.

Comment: How are you able to compare the timings? Note that for `WP_Query` a search is  just  the `s` parameter, it doesn't have options to break that apart into sub-options like just search the title, or just search the content. It sounds like you need to raise a support issue with the plugin that implements multi language functionality, as that's the part that's making it slow