# Filter wordpress posts without searching the keywords in the post content

Tags: php, posts, filters, hooks

We've a courses website where we want to filter posts/courses by the keywords present in the category and/or title. Currently when filtering, the keyword is also being searched in the post content which is what we want to exclude. Is there a way to exclude searching in the post content via a `hook` or `filter` in wordpress ?

Attached is the image of the search results where the first search result doesn't contain a computer word either in the title or the category but still it shows in the results.

**Update**
Forgot to mention that it's a custom post type `job_listing`.

[image]

Comment: There is a `posts_search` hook you can use. Here's an example that searches only post titles: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11822/how-to-limit-search-to-post-titles - you would basically copy most of the `WP_Query` class and remove the `post_content LIKE` part.

Comment: How would this work for both the `post title` & `category`  ?@WebElaine